# Calculate gradient, then partial derivative.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given

$w =  x^{2}yz + y^{2} + {z^2}$

Also

$x = s*\sin(t)$

$y = s*\cos(t)$

$z = \ln(st)$

Find $\nabla w$, $\frac{\partial w}{\partial s}$

So, I worked my way through finding $\nabla w$

$w_x = 2xyz$

$w_y = x^{2}z + 2y$

$w_z = x^{2}y + 2z$

which rendered me $\nabla w$ as:

$\langle 2xyz , x^{2}z + 2y , x^{2}y + 2z \rangle$

Now, I am confused here. Is this correct, or did  have to substitute the values of $x,y,z$ first, then find grad? Or simply substitute them after finding the above calculation. If thats the case, I proceed to:

$\langle 2(s*\sin(t))yz , x^{2z} + 2(s*\cos(t)) , x^{2y} + 2(\ln(st))\rangle$

Would I be correct thus far? Now I do not know how to go about doing a partial derivative on a vector function?

Comment: Your gradient looks all right.  To differentiate your gradient as you've written it, you will need to replace $x , y, $ and $z$ in each component and then find the partial derivatives of the resulting component expressions with respect to $s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible "gradients" of $w$ depending on whether thinks about it as a function of the $x,y,z$ space or as a function of the parameters $t,s$. You worked out the first one, which is almost certainly the one which is meant.

For the second part, assuming we hold $t$ fixed, there are two ways to go. Either

- go back to the definition of $w$ and substitute in $x,y,z$ in terms of $t,s$, then do a derivative with respect to $s$ directly; or
- use the chain rule, which says
  $$\partial w/\partial s = \sum \partial w/\partial x_i \times \partial x_i/\partial s = \nabla w \cdot (\partial x/\partial s,\partial y/\partial s,\partial z/\partial s)$$